# Slide In From Left When You Don't Know The Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element and I don't know its width. I want it to scroll in from the side. To do this, it has to be just to the left of the edge of the screen so I can't see it. I am willing to use JavaScript or JQuery to do this also, but I would prefer just CSS. I have seen some tutorials on how to get something to slide in from the side, but they all involve knowing the width of the element. Right now I am using the code below, however sometimes the edge shows because it is wider than 100px.

```css
.comment:hover .sender{
 margin-left: 0;
 position: relative;
}
.sender{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: -100px;
 background-color: #802629;
 color: white;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 padding: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.comment{
 border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
 border-bottom: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 4px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="sender">I have a very long name so I overflow.</div>
  some other stuff here too but this isn't important
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="sender">Someone:</div>
  some other stuff here too but this isn't important
</div>
```

Comment: Since you're using absolute positioning to hide `left:-100%` to show `left:0` [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/scvumw73/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the second element  `width:100%` so it covers all the parent width then adjust the alignement to push the first element on the left. On hover you simply decrease the width:

```css
.sender {
  background-color: #802629;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.comment {
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 4px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; /* push to the left */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment>span {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* disable the shrink */
  flex-grow: 1; /* will grow even when width = 0*/
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.comment:hover span {
  width: 0%;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="sender">I have a very long name so I overflow.</div>
  <span>some other stuff here too but this isn't important</span>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="sender">Someone:</div>
  <span>some other stuff here too but this isn't important</span>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <div class="sender">A:</div>
  <span>some other stuff here too but this isn't important</span>
</div>
```

Another idea without flexbox and extra wrapper for the text where you can also have the text going to the next line when pushed:

```css
.sender {
  background-color: #802629;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float:left;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  max-width:0;
  margin-right: 4px;
  transition: max-width 0.3s;
}

.comment {
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 4px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment:hover .sender {
  max-width:100%;
  transition:max-width 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="sender">I have a very long name so I overflow.</div>
  some other stuff here too but this isn't important some other stuff here too but  stuff here too but
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="sender">Someone:</div>
  some other stuff here too but this isn't important
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <div class="sender">A:</div>
  some other stuff here too but this isn't important
</div>
```

Comment: Looks great, though on small screens, the name becomes multiple rows instead of the "not important" text going underneath it. I think it'd be nice if you could solve that too.

Comment: @icecub it will depend on the OP need. He is using flexbox where text doesn't wrap but I will add another idea

Answer (score 0):

What about .sender margin-left to be **-100%** instead of '-100px'.

Test it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-btzvgj